# Thread local RefCell as replacement to local variable in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust.
I'm trying to implement alternative to private variable inside classes to keep Postgres connection inside Struct. Currently I have:

```
    thread_local! {

        static CONNECTION: RefCell<Option<Connection>> = RefCell::new(None);
    }
```

Than I initialize it like this:

```
        PostgresDb::CONNECTION.with(|pg_connection| {
            *pg_connection.borrow_mut() = Some(connection)
        });
```

It works fine.
But when I try to execute some query on it like this:

```
PostgresDb::CONNECTION.with(|pg_connection| {
            *pg_connection.borrow_mut().map(|conn| conn.execute("Select * from test", &[]));
}
```

I'm getting:

```
type `std::option::Option<Result<u64, psql::Error>>` cannot be dereferenced
```

If I change it to:

```
PostgresDb::CONNECTION.with(|pg_connection| {
            pg_connection.borrow_mut().map(|conn| conn.execute("Select * from test", &[]));
```

I'm getting:

```
cannot move out of dereference of `RefMut<'_, std::option::Option<psql::Connection>>`
move occurs because value has type `std::option::Option<psql::Connection>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: You probably need [`Option::as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut): `pg_connection.borrow_mut().as_mut().map(...)`.

Comment: Thank you @user4815162342 Are you willing to write it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Option::map()` consumes the option in order to pass the closure it receives the content of the option. Since `conn.execute` only needs a (mutable) reference to the option contents, you can create a new `Option` whose content references the contents of the original one, and pass *that* to `map()`. This is easiest to accomplish with the [`Option::as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) convenience method:

```
pg_connection.borrow_mut().as_mut().map(|conn| conn.execute(...));
```

In most cases the error "cannot move out of ... `Option`" can be resolved with the use of `Option::as_ref` or `Option::as_mut`.